# PSReadLine throw exception after upgrading to PS 7.2

Tags: powershell, psreadline

Exception thrown after upgrading to Powershell 7.2.0 while using PSReadLine

```
### Environment
PSReadLine: 2.2.0-beta1
PowerShell: 7.2.0
OS: Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
BufferWidth: 309
BufferHeight: 55

Last 0 Keys


System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.Subsystem.PredictionResult' from assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.PSReadLine.Polyfiller, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.PredictionViewBase.Reset()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.PredictionInlineView.Reset()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Prediction.Reset()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.Initialize(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine.ReadLine(Runspace runspace, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/2989), the issue can be fixed by

> This issue was fixed in 2.2.0-beta3 version of PSReadLine. You can fix
> this by upgrading to the latest 2.2.0-beta4 version of PSReadLine.
> Instructions for doing so:
>
> 1: stop all instances of **pwsh**.
>
> 2: from cmd.exe run:
>
> ```
> pwsh -noprofile -command "Install-Module PSReadLine -AllowPrerelease -Force"
> ```

Further if you want previous setup uninstalled, follow as

> If you want to remove that beta version of PSReadLine and use the
> 2.1.0 version of PSReadLine that's shipped with PowerShell 7.2, you can:
>
> 1: run `pwsh -noprofile -noninteractive` to start pwsh without loading PSReadLine
>
> 2: run `Uninstall-Module -Name PSReadLine -RequiredVersion <2.2.0-beta1 or 2.2.0-beta2> -AllowPrerelease` to remove the module.
> Or, you can manually remove that module folder.